# Google Functions + Execute bash script on instance

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine

I need to execute a bash script/command within a Google compute instance using Google Functions and get a response.
AWS has an agent called SSM that let me do that with no hassle using Lambda, nevertheless I did not find anything like that on Google Cloud. 
On AWS using a nodejs lambda I use the following example:

```
ssm.sendCommand({
      DocumentName: documentName,
      InstanceIds: [ instanceId ],
      TimeoutSeconds: 3600,
      Parameters: { 
        'commands' : commands
      }
    }
```

How can I achieve what I want on Google Cloud? Thank you.

Comment: If you have SSH access to the compute instance then you can use any SSH-based remote command execution library, like Paramiko for Python.

Comment: By doing a quick search, I found this article from Medium that could be helpful: https://medium.com/google-cloud/start-stop-compute-engine-instance-from-cloud-function-bf9ae5199609 

Nevertheless, I haven't tried to create a scenario for trying this but looks promising.

Comment: Let's just check one thing because I'm not sure everyone is reading your question correctly ... your question is "I have code running in Google Cloud Functions and I want it to be able to execute commands remotely on a GCE instance (for example over SSH)". Is that right?

Answer (score 5):

The nature of Google Cloud Functions is that it is the most abstract of the Serverless paradigms.  It assumes that all you are providing is stateless logic to be executed in one of the supported languages.  You aren't supposed to know nor care how that logic is executed.  Running `bash` (for example) makes an assumption that your Cloud Function is running in a Unix like environment where bash is available.  While this is likely to be a true statement, it isn't part of the "core" contract that you have with the Cloud Function environment.

An alternative solution I would suggest is to study Google's Cloud Run concept.  Just like Cloud Functions, Cloud Run is serverless (you don't provision any servers and it scales to zero) but the distinction is that what is executed is a docker container.  Within that container, your "code" within is executed in the container environment when called. Google spins up / spins down these containers as needed to satisfy your incoming load.  Since it is running in a container, you have 100% control over what your logic does ... including running bash commands and providing any scripts or other environment needed to be able to run.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. You can perform some actions such as [start a VM or stop it](https://www.infiflex.com/starting-and-stopping-a-vm-using-cloud-function-node-js--python) from a Cloud Function, but you can't get or list the dirs within a VM. In this case, the Compute Engine API is being used, but only the is reached.
The workaround would be to create a request handler in your VM in order to could be rached by the CF. The proper security would be implemented in order to avoid security issues and requests from anonymous callers. You might use the public IP to reach your VM.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a Bash script on Google Cloud Run with a Bash Docker image. As an example - https://github.com/sethvargo/cloud-run-bash-example

Then you can call this Cloud Run service from your other existing Google Cloud Functions, AppEngine etc.

Comment: The link 404s now